# How do I save a Netscape style cookies.txt file using Python 2.7 and Requests?

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, cookielib, cookiejar

I am using requests to fetch a webpage and I would like to save the cookies in a Netscape-style cookies.txt file.  How can I achieve this?  I have tried the following:

```
import requests
import cookielib

url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
ua = ("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) "
      "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0")
headers = {'user-agent': ua}

mcj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar()
requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=mcj)
mcj.save('cookies.txt')
print open('cookies.txt').read()
```

but it just creates a cookie file with no cookies, so the output is:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.
```

Comment: What version of Requests do you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for still looking into this.
>>> print requests.__version__  
1.2.0
>>> print requests.__build__  
66048

Answer (score -1):

Cookies sent by server are in the `cookies` attribute of response object; see [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#main-interface) of `requests.Response` class.

Comment: @HolyMackerel I changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I removed my comments.